# Is there a formula for the area under $\tanh(x)$?

Tags: calculus, area, hyperbolic-functions

I understand trigonometry but I've never used hyperbolic functions before.

> Is there a formula for the area under $\tanh(x)$?

I've looked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) and [Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tanh.html) but they don't say if there's a formula or not.

I tried to work it out myself and I got this far:

$\tanh(x) = {\sinh(x)\over\cosh(x)} = {1-e^{-2x}\over 1+e^{-2x}} = {e^{2x}-1\over e^{2x}+1} = {e^{2x}+1-2\over e^{2x}+1} = 1-{2\over e^{2x}+1}$

Now I'm stuck. I don't know if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: Do you have a formula for the area under $\tan$? If so, append $h$ to all trigonometric functions occurring. -That works, really.

Comment: That sounds like magic=) Can you explain why this does work? In the case of $\tan$ you'd also have to flip the sign, as $\int \tan x dx = - \log \cos x$

Comment: Have you looked at Wikipedia? Look again, section [Hyperbolic function # Standard integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_integrals). It says $\int \tanh(ax)\, dx = a^{-1}\,\ln(\cosh(ax)) + C$.

Comment: @CiaPan I'm really bad with the names of functions so I didn't realise the area under a curve is calculated with integrals until after the first answer was posted.

Comment: There isn't a formula for "the area under $\tanh(x)$" because this is a meaningless statement. There is a formula for the area under *the graph of* $\tanh$, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hyperbolic tangent can be integrated. First we simplify the formula, which can easily be derived using the definitions of the hyperbolic cosine and the hyperbolic sine and their relation:

$\tanh x  = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x} = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=1-\frac{2}{e^{2x}+1}$

When you integrate, you will get

$$\int \tanh(x) dx = \log(\cosh(x))+c$$

PS: [Wolfram knows very well!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+tanh+x)

Comment: Perhaps more natural to a calculus student is to let $u=\cosh x$.

Comment: ...which I left as an exercise to the reader=) You could also directly see that $\cosh' x = \sinh x$ and perform the substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, we know $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$  & $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$, hence the area under $\tanh(x)$ is
$$\int \tanh(x)\ dx=\int \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh (x)}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{d(e^x+e^{-x})}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$
let $e^x+e^{-x}=t\implies d(e^x+e^{-x})=dt $, 
$$=\int \frac{dt}{t}=\ln|t|+C$$
$$=\color{red}{\ln(e^x+e^{-x})+C}$$

Comment: First of all I think this might be a misleading notation. Why would you replace $(e^x-e^{-x})dx$ by $d(e^x+e^{-x})$?

Comment: Alright, it's done only for substitution, notice $$\frac{d}{dx}(e^x+e^{-x})=e^x-e^{-x}\implies d(e^x+e^{-x})=(e^x-e^{-x})dx$$

Comment: I think the more intuitive way how most people learn it, is to define a funciton $u:= e^x+e^{-x}$, take the derivative $\frac{du}{dx} = e^x-e^{-x}$ and plut those two into your expression, and you'll get $\int \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}} dx = \int \frac{du}{u}$, which lets you even omit that step that seemed so confiusing to me.

Answer (score 3):

Why all those difficult substitutions and jabbers? 
Just observe that we can use the logarithm derivative formula:

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\ \text{d} x = \ln(f(x)) + C$$

thence, having $\tanh(x) = \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ it comes easy to get the result

$$\int\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}\ \text{d}x = \ln(\cosh(x)) + C$$

Comment: In general a primitive of $f'/f$ is $\ln |f|$, not $\ln f$ (here it doesn't matter because $\cosh > 0$ anyway).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You're right, I forgot the Abs sign! Fortunately in this case is the same ^^